# Check for changes in specifics files with batch not working as expected

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-line, cmd

I have differents files, and I want to check for any changes in any of them, using batch. This is what I have:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "list=test.txt test1.txt"

:loop
timeout -t 1 >nul
for %%j in (%list%) do (
    REM Here only prints test.txt       
    echo %%j
    for %%i in (%%j) do echo %%~ai|find "a">nul || goto :loop
    echo file was changed %%j
    attrib -a %%j
)
goto :loop
```

If I use only one file, works, but not with two or more. The idea is, that `echo file was changed %%j` only outputs the correct file, and not both.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

If I do some changes:

```
@echo off
title LAN chat reader
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "list=test.txt test1.txt"

:loop
timeout -t 1 >nul
for %%j in (%list%) do (
    echo %%j
    echo %%~aj|find "a">nul || goto :loop
    echo file was changed %%j
    attrib -a %%j
)
goto :loop
```

works, but only alerts me the changes in the second file, after I make changes in the first. I can understand that the problem is in the loop, so there is where I'm confused.

Comment: Once you break out of the loop you can't process the other file.  Why are you breaking out of the loop when the attribute is not found?

Comment: Just for testing, but it's still not working

Comment: Also, your find command will always be false because you are looking for a lower case a.  Either use the `/I` switch with the `FIND` command or upper case the letter.

Comment: I'd suggest a couple of things. #1: Use 'call :CheckFile "%%j"' instead of a nested for loop - makes things easier to read. #2: you can use DIR to check the attribute a bit more directly: dir /aa %%j > nul 2>&1 && attrib -a %%j

Comment: You also do not even need the second `FOR` command.  You could have just used `echo %%~aj|find "A">nul`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments, but it could be more helpfull if you type a properly answer with the correct code.

Comment: @joeking, all yours to answer. I like your idea the best.

Comment: @robe007, I like to teach more then provide direct answers.  If I can lead the horse to the water and make them drink it, I get a lot more satisfaction out of helping.

Comment: @Squashman hahaha, thanks I have understood somethings with your comments, but it would be nice a complete answer !

Comment: In regards to your 2nd try you still did not change the FIND command parameters that I mentioned in a previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a couple of things.

1: Use

```
call :CheckFile "%%j"
```

instead of a nested for loop - makes things easier to read.

2: you can use DIR to check the attribute a bit more directly:

```
dir /aa %%j > nul 2>&1 && attrib -a %%j
```

Both together looks something like:

```
:loop
    timeout -t 1 >nul
    for %%j in (%list%) do call :CheckFile "%%j"
    goto :loop

:CheckFile
    echo %1
    dir /aa %1 > nul 2>&1 || goto :EOF
    echo file was changed %1
    attrib -a %1
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: Yesss, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks my friend !